# Displaying condensed relative date timer in watchOS WidgetKit?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, widgetkit

I'm creating a watchOS complication using WidgetKit and SwiftUI. I'm trying to add use the date style for the Text view, but it uses a long version:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct MyGaugeCircularAccessoryView: View {
    let gradient = Gradient(stops: [.init(color: .red, location: 0), .init(color: .green, location: 0.25)])

    var body: some View {
        Gauge(value: 0.6) {
            Text("ABC")
        } currentValueLabel: {
            Text(.now + 60 * 60 * 3, style: .relative)
        }
        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircular)
        .tint(gradient)
    }
}

struct MyGaugeCircularAccessoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyGaugeCircularAccessoryView()
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .accessoryCircular))
    }
}
```

The is what it looks like:

[image]

Previously, I could create a complication like this:

```swift
CLKRelativeDateTextProvider(date: .now, style: .naturalAbbreviated, units: [.hour])
```

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this with the `Text(date:style:)` view?

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?